# Replace string between given string and line break

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a file which includes only once `search_for_me=12.21/13.31/14` followed by a `line break`.  I wish to replace `12.21/13.31/14` with `21.12/44.22/44`.  How can this be accomplished?

```
<?php
/*
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string)."\n\n\n";
//April1,2003
*/
$string = file_get_contents('test.conf');

$string= <<<EOT
bla bla bla

search_for_me=12.21/13.31/14

bla bla bla
EOT;

echo $string."\n\n";

$replace = "21.12/44.22/44";

$search = "/[^search_for_me=](.*)[^\n]/";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string)."\n\n";

echo 'done';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$string= <<<EOT
bla bla bla

search_for_me=12.21/13.31/14

bla bla bla
EOT;

printf("-String without replace:\n\n%s\n\n", $string);

$replace = '21.12/44.22/44';

$pattern = '/(?<=search_for_me\=)(.*)/';

$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);

printf("-String with replace:\n\n%s", $new_string);
```

I use the positive lookbehind [HERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks Kip,  One of these days, I really need to learn this!  Positive lookbehind is making my head spin, so might take me some time understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Here i am using regex to search and replace,

**Regex:** `/(search_for_me).*?\n/`, This will match `search_for_me` and till `\n`

**Replacement**: `'\1=21.12/44.22/44'."\n"` Here `\1` will contain first captured group `search_for_me`.

[**Try  this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782155)

```
<?php
/*
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string)."\n\n\n";
//April1,2003
*/
$string = file_get_contents('test.conf');

$string= <<<EOT
bla bla bla

search_for_me=12.21/13.31/14

bla bla bla
EOT;

echo $string."\n\n";

$replace = "21.12/44.22/44";

$search = "/(search_for_me)=.*?\n/";
echo preg_replace($search,'\1=21.12/44.22/44'."\n",$string)."\n\n";
```

Comment: Thank you.  Could you correct my interpretation.  So match `search_for_me=` and store it as the first captured group, include one using `?` or many using `*` characters as the replacement until getting to a new line indicated by `\n`, and then replace the match with the capture group plus the replacement value?

Comment: @user1032531 `.*` is match all where as `.*?` make it lazy so it will match all till the first occurrence of `\n`

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Thanks